# Sorting by high to low price is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, product-variations

I have WooCommerce, installed at WP and some products, which have variations with prices.
Each variation have field Regular price, and I need to sort by this price in the catalog.
Sort by low to high is working well, but high to low is not working properly.
It saved in database table wp_options as I found, not in wp_postmeta.
В базе в таблице wp_options как я понял это хранится, а не в wp_postmeta.
There is such JSON:

```
{"version":"1586002626","f9e544f77b7eac7add281ef28ca5559f":{"price":{"267":"20.00","269":"100.00"},"regular_price":{"267":"20.00","269":"100.00"},"sale_price":{"267":"20.00","269":"100.00"}},"98f9c03adb427b329f828827eb33e0bf":{"price":{"267":"20.00","269":"100.00"},"regular_price":{"267":"20.00","269":"100.00"},"sale_price":{"267":"20.00","269":"100.00"}}}
```

In functions.php I tried to do many things, now there is such code, but it's not sorting by ?orderby=price-desc.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $args['orderby'] = '_transient_wc_var_prices';
    $args['order'] = 'desc';
    return $args;
}
```

Is there any ways to fix that?

Comment: Here is functions.php https://github.com/compplace/wpsort/blob/master/functions.php

Comment: What do you get with this code? Blank page? No refreshing?

Comment: No, I get wrong sorting: 20, 20, 15, 20, isnstead of 20, 20, 20, 15

Comment: Does the 'asc' function worked? Your reference code is using:

`$args['orderby'] = '_price'; $args['order'] = ''; $args['meta_key'] = '_transient_wc_var_prices';`

While you used

`$args['orderby'] = '_transient_wc_var_prices'; $args['order'] = 'desc';`

Comment: as I see its working, but I think its sorting by date, sol its looks like its sorting right, but sorting by desc is not working

Comment: I see you said your data is in _options not in _postmeta. So you changed the query. I guess your problem is there. The woocommerce still have _regular_price and _sale_price so it also may be mixing those.

Comment: no, I didnt change anything. and as I see it sorts by max price of producta variations. is there any way to sort by min price?